# Comparing sdcard paths

Tags: android

Device 1

`/sdcard` attached to real sd card

`/mnt/sdcard` attached to real sd card

Device 2

`/sdcard` attached to internal memory

`/mnt/sdcard` attached to internal memory

`/external_storage`(something like this) to real sd card

.
.

`/sdcard` and `/mnt/sdcard` seems to have the same location. Always ?

My question is, how do I know if they attached to same directory ?

I tried `new File(path1).equals(new File(path2));` but it return false. Only way I see is, create a hidden file with unique id and check the existence in both paths.

PS : I'm aware of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. But I need these paths for some specific purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new File("/sdcard").getCanonicalPath().equals(new File("/mnt/sdcard").getCanonicalPath())
```

Omitted are exception handling and other niceties. Note, however, that ObieMD5 is correct, and you should not be doing this, as you can see from the list of paths in the answer above.

Also note that this method will only resolve symlinks; if your device uses mount instead to have the same space accessible from two locations, this method will not work.

Comment: can you explain this part "Also note that this method will only resolve symlinks; if your device uses mount instead to have the same space accessible from two locations, this method will not work."

Comment: It is possible to mount one physical device to two places in the filesystem - in theory, I've never seen any Android system like this. Normally, as mentioned in the other answer, a physical device will be mounted to one place and then a symlink created to access it from another.

Answer (score 4):

/sdcard and /mnt/sdcard are not always the same.  There are many paths that can exsist such as:

```
/emmc 
/mnt/sdcard/external_sd
/mnt/external_sd
/sdcard/sd
/mnt/sdcard/bpemmctest
/mnt/sdcard/_ExternalSD
/mnt/sdcard-ext
/mnt/Removable/MicroSD
/Removable/MicroSD
/mnt/external1
/mnt/extSdCard
/mnt/extsd
/mnt/usb_storage <-- usb flash mount
/mnt/extSdCard <-- usb flash mount
/mnt/UsbDriveA <-- usb flash mount
/mnt/UsbDriveB <-- usb flash mount
```

There should be no reason that you would need a direct path hard coded to the internal or external memory when they make functions available for that.  Anything that you are hard coding will be the same as what you get back from the functions that you have listed only the will be for that specific devices.

This will give you a string of the absolute path to a file on the external storage:

```
String myPath = sdcardEnvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folder file is in/file you want path to";
```

And this will get you the path your applications internal storage:

```
this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()
```

You cannot always access the external SD card from code because of the way that newer versions of android partition itself.  Here is statement directly from android dev site:

`It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case, the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot access it`

Comment: then just use the functions. Unless you do the direct paths for your device only, but that would defeat the purpose. Even if you are testing code, you should test the right code.

Comment: What function is going to tell me, that sdcard from root and sdcard from from mnt are same ? I'm not writing file to storage or something, all I need is compare.

Comment: what do you mean? what are you trying to compare?

Comment: The paths `/sdcard` and `/mnt/sdcard`, are they same or not ?

Comment: Mostly likely /sdcard is a symbolic link to /mnt/sdcard however, it is not always true.  In some devices it can lead to /mnt/extStorage or any of the variations listed above.

Comment: @xmenW.K. check updated post and if you want to continue, I suggest we go to a chat so this doesn't get closed for off topic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33940/discussion-between-xmen-w-k-and-obiemd5)

Answer (score 0):

> attached to real sd card

The Android SDK, at present, has no concept of "real sd card". There is [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). The definition of where external storage resides is up to the device manufacturer.

> attached to internal memory

Those paths at best refer to external storage, and at worst do not exist.

> /sdcard and /mnt/sdcard seems to have the same location. Always ?

No. Those paths may not even exist on some devices, as there is no requirement that they exist, and modern devices do not use those paths. Always use methods on `Environment` or `Context` to find locations on external storage.